# change "0" to names in Json file

Tags: php, json, oracle

I am using PHP array and outputing to JSON string.  I want to convert "0" in the json format to lets say calling them "items". Since while importing this to oracle db it says expecting names instead of zero. When I change the index ( 0, 1, 2 ) to be called just items, it works normally.

Here is the PHP array, and I am outputting it as json.

```
 $data = array(

                        'INDIVIDUAL_SALUTATION' => $salution,
                        'INDIVIDUAL_FIRST_NAME' => $firstname,
                        'INDIVIDUAL_LAST_NAME' => $lastname,
                        'GENDER' => $gender,
                        'DATE_OF_BIRTH' => $result['Birthday'],
                        'EMAIL_ID' => $result['Email'],
                        'MOBILE_NUMBER' =>$result['Phone'],
                        'MOBILE_COUNTRY_CODE' => substr($result['Phone'], 1, 3),
                        'OCCUPATION' => null,
                        'OCCUPATION_STATUS' => null,
                        'ADDRESS_LINE1' => $result['Address_street'],
                        'TOWN' => $result['Address_city'],
                        'POSTAL_CODE' => $result['Address_zip'],
                        'COUNTRY' => $result['country_name'],
                        'CUSTOMER_NUMBER' => $result['Owner'],
                        'POLICY_START_DATE' => $result['paid_thru_date'],
                        'POLICY_END_DATE' => $result['duedate'],
                        'LOAN_AGREEMENT_NUMBER' => $result['ORIG_ID'],
                        'REPAYABLE_AMOUNT' => $result['repayable_amount'],
                        'FINANCE_TERM_MONTHS' => $result['finance_term_months'],
                        'MONTHLY_INSTALLMENT' => $result['monthly_installment'],
                        'AMOUNT_INSURED' => $result['amount_insured'],
                        'CURRENCY_ID' => $result['Abbreviation']
                    ); 

                    $jsonArray[] = $data;
                }
                $mainInfo = array(
                            'SRC_NAME' => 'AEX',
                            "RUN_NUMBER" => 1,
                            "RUN_DATE" => date("Ymd"),
                            "RUN_NO_OF_RECORDS" => $arrayCount,
                            "YTD_NO_OF_RECORDS" => $arrayCount
                        );

                $finalArray = array_merge($jsonArray , $mainInfo);

                $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
                $this->output->set_output(json_encode($finalArray));


 $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
 $this->output->set_output(json_encode($mainInfo));
```

Here is the output

```
  {
   "0":{
      "INDIVIDUAL_SALUTATION":"MR",
      "INDIVIDUAL_FIRST_NAME":"borrower",
      "INDIVIDUAL_LAST_NAME":"three",
      "GENDER":"M",
      "DATE_OF_BIRTH":"1993-09-17",
      "EMAIL_ID":"borrowerthree@aurorax.co",
      "MOBILE_NUMBER":"+3581466144569",
      "MOBILE_COUNTRY_CODE":"358",
      "OCCUPATION":null,
      "OCCUPATION_STATUS":null,
      "ADDRESS_LINE1":"Vaskivuorentie 22B",
      "TOWN":"Vantaa",
      "POSTAL_CODE":"01600",
      "COUNTRY":"Finland",
      "CUSTOMER_NUMBER":"772",
      "POLICY_START_DATE":"2017-01-02",
      "POLICY_END_DATE":"2017-07-01",
      "LOAN_AGREEMENT_NUMBER":"7",
      "REPAYABLE_AMOUNT":"50.42",
      "FINANCE_TERM_MONTHS":"6",
      "MONTHLY_INSTALLMENT":"8.40",
      "AMOUNT_INSURED":"50.42",
      "CURRENCY_ID":"EUR"
   },
   "1":{
      "INDIVIDUAL_SALUTATION":"MR",
      "INDIVIDUAL_FIRST_NAME":"borrower",
      "INDIVIDUAL_LAST_NAME":"three",
      "GENDER":"M",
      "DATE_OF_BIRTH":"1993-09-17",
      "EMAIL_ID":"borrowerthree@aurorax.co",
      "MOBILE_NUMBER":"+3581466144569",
      "MOBILE_COUNTRY_CODE":"358",
      "OCCUPATION":null,
      "OCCUPATION_STATUS":null,
      "ADDRESS_LINE1":"Vaskivuorentie 22B",
      "TOWN":"Vantaa",
      "POSTAL_CODE":"01600",
      "COUNTRY":"Finland",
      "CUSTOMER_NUMBER":"772",
      "POLICY_START_DATE":"2017-01-02",
      "POLICY_END_DATE":"2017-07-01",
      "LOAN_AGREEMENT_NUMBER":"9",
      "REPAYABLE_AMOUNT":"40.35",
      "FINANCE_TERM_MONTHS":"6",
      "MONTHLY_INSTALLMENT":"6.73",
      "AMOUNT_INSURED":"40.35",
      "CURRENCY_ID":"EUR"
   },
   "2":{
      "INDIVIDUAL_SALUTATION":"MR",
      "INDIVIDUAL_FIRST_NAME":"borrower",
      "INDIVIDUAL_LAST_NAME":"two",
      "GENDER":"M",
      "DATE_OF_BIRTH":"1993-09-17",
      "EMAIL_ID":"borrowertwo@aurorax.co",
      "MOBILE_NUMBER":"+358466144569123",
      "MOBILE_COUNTRY_CODE":"358",
      "OCCUPATION":null,
      "OCCUPATION_STATUS":null,
      "ADDRESS_LINE1":"Vaskivuorentie 22B",
      "TOWN":"Vantaa",
      "POSTAL_CODE":"01600",
      "COUNTRY":"Finland",
      "CUSTOMER_NUMBER":"770",
      "POLICY_START_DATE":"2017-01-02",
      "POLICY_END_DATE":"2017-07-01",
      "LOAN_AGREEMENT_NUMBER":"11",
      "REPAYABLE_AMOUNT":"99.84",
      "FINANCE_TERM_MONTHS":"6",
      "MONTHLY_INSTALLMENT":"16.64",
      "AMOUNT_INSURED":"99.84",
      "CURRENCY_ID":"EUR"
   },
   "RUN_NUMBER":1,
   "RUN_DATE":"20170109"
}
```

What I am trying to do is make it look like instead of 0 have `'items' : {}` and then move on, so I can import it to oracle. 
How can I achieve this with php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `array_merge`, put the array in an element of `$mainInfo`:

```
$mainInfo['items'] = $jsonArray;
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($mainInfo));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create index variable and make it to zero

`$index = 0`

And change this `$jsonArray[] = $data;` to this `$jsonArray['item' .$index++] = $data;`

Hope that helps